# Visual representation of chordal metric in $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})$

Tags: metric-spaces, projective-space

I am reading a book and they are using the cordal metric in $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})$ defined as:

$\rho(P_1,P_2)= \frac{\mid X_1Y_2 - X_2Y_1 \mid}{\sqrt{\mid X_1^2\mid+\mid Y_1^2 \mid}\sqrt{\mid X_2^2\mid+\mid Y_2^2 \mid}}$

for $P_i=(X_i,Y_i)$.

Can anyone give me a visual representation or explanation of what this metric measures? I guessed arc lenght but the lack of trigonomic functions in the metric quickly changed my mind.

Comment: I hope you know that P^1(C) is isomorphic to the Riemann sphere S^2. Here, the geometric meaning is evident, because as the name suggests, the chordal metric refers to the length of the straight line segment (chord) (in R^3) joining two points on the Riemann sphere (which we think of as sitting inside R^3).

Comment: @peek-a-boo yes, I finally understood exactl that, I was working on the Riemman sphere that is why I thought of arc lenght. But I did some mapping and used the standard metric on R^3 and it became that function.